# Added Bootstrap header and now the component is duplicating

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have added a Navbar from Bootstrap to a React App and for some reason, it is duplicating when I render the app.  Not sure what is happening.  Here is the code from below is my headercomponent.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar.jsx';




 class HeaderName extends Component {
 render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
        </div>
        <h1>The AquaStars New Website.</h1>
        <img src="../public/images/picture_swimmers.png" />

       </div>

      )
    }
  }

 export default HeaderName;
```

Below is the Navbar.jsx component.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
 import './Navbar.css';


class Navbar extends Component {
render() {
    return (

        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Top navbar</a>
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li className="nav-item active">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </nav>


    );
  }
 }

 export default Navbar;
```

Below is the index.js.  This is where I think the problem is.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HeaderName from './components/header';
import FooterName from './components/footer';
import DescripTitle from './components/descrip';
import DescripName from './components/intro';

//create a new componet.  Produce some HTML.
// const App = function() {
//     return <div>Welcome to Aquastars Website</div>;
// }

 const App = () => {
 return (
    <div>
        <Router>
            <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HeaderName}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
        <HeaderName />
        <DescripName />
        <DescripTitle />
        <FooterName />
    </div>
    );
 }
  //Take this component's generated HTML and put it
  // on the page(in the DOM).
   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you also share `Navbar` component?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not rendering the `Navbar` component in your `app.js/index.js` or wherever the `headerName` component is being imported. Can you post these files as well? What is inside the `Navbar` component. More information is needed.

-EDIT-

You can make a new Component that brings In any page contents into a "page component" then in your render:

```
    <HeaderName/>
    <Router exact path="/somedirectory" component{yourPageComponent}/>
    <FooterName/>
```

This will make sure that header and footer are rendered on every page but only certain content is rendered on route changes. Cheers.

Comment: I think this is the problem. This is in the index.js ```<Router>
                <div>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HeaderName}/>
                </div>
            </Router>```

Comment: Can you post index.js? That code states that the HeaderName component will only be mounted when the root directory is hit.

Comment: Yep so you are rendering HeaderName twice. You are calling it on specifically when the root directory is hit and also on every page so any time you are on the home page it will render twice. Ill edit my answer with a solution

Comment: Certainly that's not the problem, also if you want the header on each an every page should get rid of exact path line, and divs enclosing Route are not necessary.

Comment: How is that not the problem? @vitomadio

Comment: Upss. Didn't see the last edit (index.js file), yeap indeed he is calling it twice.